# Importing an activity on MOODLE 4.0

Tags: moodle

I am trying to importing a quiz from one course to another on Moodle Version 4.0 but I am failing to get proper steps. Please assist.

Unlike old versions Moodle importing settings were on the top left gear settings on the course page but on Moodle 4.0 the interface is totally different.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the course menu, click on "more" then select "course reuse"

Select a course, then select the activities to import

[image: Screenshot of the "Course Reuse" menu option in Moodle]

Comment: Also, just for reference, I'm happy to help but StackOverflow is for developer issues. Your question might get down voted or closed, which will affect your reputation on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks Russell, okay noted your reference!